# About parallel circuit

Tags: power, energy

Consider a power source supplying 240 v 50/60hz 6amp I know that there is nothing like it but I chose that for my comfort of understanding now if I connect 15 loads drawing 240 v 0.35 amps in parallel to the source which all combined draws 5.2 amps will this circuit work correctly.as I heard that voltage doesn't change in parallel circuit regardless of loads.so just say will the above circuit work wothout any voltage drops.sorry for the silly question as i am new to this.

Comment: In reality there will be volt drops. In theory (depending on how deep you model things), there may not be volt drops. There may be greater or lesser volt drops depending how you interpret the question - hint - always better to draw a schematic of what you mean rather than use potentially ambiguous words.

Answer (score 0):

There will be some voltage drop but it is negligible.

Voltage will be exactly common when you are going to connect all the loads at a common point.

If the conductor length increases there will be change in resistance which will going to effect the voltage ( I mean if you connect loads to a common wire but at multiple points ... the far end will receive less voltage than the Near end.